# sql string extraction using c# managed code

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I have 2 functions in a SQL Server DB project.

`GetCatalogueNo` has the Regex pattern written in the function.

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlString GetCatalogueNo(string originalString)
{
   Regex r1 = new Regex("\\d{7}|\\d{3}/\\d{4}");               

    return r1.Match(originalString).Groups[0].Value;
}
```

In `ExtractText`, I'm passing the Regex pattern as a parameter.

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlString ExtractText(string originalString, string pattern)
{
    Regex r1 = new Regex(pattern);

    return r1.Match(originalString).Groups[0].Value;
}
```

Compiled code on SQL Server works fine for: `GetCatalogueNo`

```
SELECT  dbo.GetCatalogueNo('xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 9999999 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx .....')
```

Returns: 9999999

Compiled code on SQL Server does not return anything for: `ExtractText`

```
SELECT dbo.[ExtractText] ('xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 9999999 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx .....', '\\d{7}|\\d{3}/\\d{4}')
```

I wish to know how is the second parameter in `dbo.[ExtractText]` passed and what is missing please.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved the same result. It was the escape characters \ that was causing the issue.

SELECT dbo.[ExtractText] ('xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 9999999 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx .....', '\d{7}|\d{3}/\d{4}') returns the same result as GetCatalogueNo.